# Manipulate/Animate a Canvas Element like this?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

When you take a look at this keyframe animation, you can see a moving image and some more adjustments. The moving image is a duplicate of one of the images which is also on the canvas.

Do you know a method to create the same animation, but for the image on the canvas?
Is it even possible to have an image on the canvas, then make the image larger for example, then move it with a scripted pattern and only show current part of the moving image in the canvas area?

```html
    <title>animate canvas image</title> 
    <h1 style="color: rgb(235, 235, 235);">1280x720 Canvas</h1>
    
    <body style = "background-color:rgb(42, 42, 42)">
    <form id='form1' style="position:relative">
    <div class="page-header"></div> 
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; -user-select: none;"></div>
    
    <!--css image animation setup-->
    <style type="text/css">
    
    .page-header:after {
      animation: move 10s steps(12) infinite;
      background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/un6UnCN.png');
      content: "";
      z-index: 100;
      height: 300%;
      left: -50%;
      opacity: 0.2;
      position: fixed;
      top: -110%;
      width: 300%;
    }
    
    @keyframes move {
      0%, 50% { transform:translate(0, 0) }
      10% { transform:translate(0%, 50%) }
      20% { transform:translate(50%, 0%) }
      30% { transform:translate(0%, 50%) }
      40% { transform:translate(50%, 0%) }
      50% { transform:translate(0%, 50%) }
      60% { transform:translate(50%, 0%) }
      70% { transform:translate(0%, 50%) }
      80% { transform:translate(50%, 0%) }
      90% { transform:translate(0%, 50%) }
    }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
        #background {display: none;}
        h1 {text-align:center; font-size:28pt; padding:50px 0; font-family:monospace;}
    </style>
    
    <div id='cnv' style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:300px"> <!--canvas position-->
        <canvas id='canvas' width='1280' height='720'> </canvas> <!--canvas size-->
        </div>
    
    <script> //canvas
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "cyan";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
    <img src = 'https://i.imgur.com/QZrUAVn.jpg' id="background" /> <!--Location background image-->
    
    <script> //background image
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var cxt = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
        var background = document.getElementById('background');
        cxt.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    //foreground image
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/un6UnCN.png'; //Location foreground image
        image.onload = function () {
            var cxt = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
            cxt.globalAlpha = 0.6;
            cxt.drawImage(image, canvas.width / 2 - image.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - image.height / 2);
        }; }); </script>
```

Comment: Here’s an [example of animation in canvas](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/engineering-projects/mechanisms-mechanical-walker/)